Parse Error When Reading GraphML File in Boost Graph Library
I'm having trouble reading a GraphML file using the Boost Graph Library. The file is created without issues, but reading it back throws a parse error. Here’s a summary of what I’m doing:

I Create my example of graph and I save it using write_graphml. This graph only has an unique Vertex Property and no Edge properties. The code used to do so is:
... variables ...

typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> Node_name;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Node_name> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Vertex> VertexMap;

Graph g;
VertexMap vertex_map;


... build the graph ...

std::string name = "../tmp/" + analyzed_file + ".graphml";
std::ofstream graph_ML(name);
boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("name", boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g));

boost::write_graphml(graph_ML, g, dp);

This code works perfectly. My file is properly saved in the desired directory.

However, when I try to read it with the following code:
std::string graph_ml_file_name = "../tmp/" + analyzed_file + ".graphml";
std::ifstream graphml_file(graph_ml_file_name);

if(!graphml_file)
{
   std::cerr << "Error opening the file" << std::endl;
   return -1;
}

boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("name", boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g));

try
{
   boost::read_graphml(graphml_file,g,dp);
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
   std::cerr << "Error opening the graphml file" << e.what() << std::endl;
   return -1;
}

I receive the error: Error opening the graphml file: parse error: unrecognized type "


I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find specifics about handling this error. Has anyone faced this issue or can suggest what might be going wrong?
I have been researching similar errors online as well as reading the official Boost Graph documentation, but I have not found a solution.

This problem cannot be reproduced on my system given the information in the question.
Here's my test program, perhaps you can spot the differences or post an edited version that DOES reproduce your problem:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

using Node_name = boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>;
using Graph     = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Node_name>;
using Vertex    = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
using VertexMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, Vertex>;

auto analyze(std::string name) {
    Graph g;
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
    boost::generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);

    VertexMap vertex_map;
    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        auto n = name + std::to_string(vd);
        put(boost::vertex_name, g, vd, name);
        vertex_map.emplace(n, vd);
    }

    auto fname = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / (name + ".graphml");
    std::ofstream graph_ML(fname);

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("name", get(boost::vertex_name, g));

    write_graphml(graph_ML, g, dp);
    return fname;
}

void reload(std::filesystem::path fname) {
    std::ifstream graphml_file(fname);

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    Graph                     g;
    dp.property("name", get(boost::vertex_name, g));

    read_graphml(graphml_file, g, dp);
}

int main() {
    auto fname = analyze("so-test");
    std::cout << "Written to " << fname << "\n";
    reload(fname);
}

With some demo runs:


Think of environment issues, where ../tmp doesn't refer to the path you think, or where the writing process still has the file open etc. (My example shows some practices to avoid these kinds of error)

Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I have tried to run your code and, again, despite the fact that the graphml file is saved properly, I'm not able to read it. I'm using exactly the code that you have kindly provided. The execution doesn't go further than the read_graphml() call. In other words, at least on my machine, I'm not able to execute any code beyond the read_graphml() line. Additionally, if I close the file (graphML.close()) immediately after the read_graphml() line, the same error appears: parse error: unrecognized type "

You will have to try and isolate the issue eg using a debugger,  manually writing a graphml file to load, double checking file locations and permissions. You can always share an example of a file that cannot be read. Oh and check that the dynamic library being used at runtime matches the one being used during compilation. Optionally don't link the library at all but include boost/libs/grap/src/graphml.cpp directly during compilation
